# Проблемы с производительностью ПК/Windows?

Tags: windows, notebook

Ситуация в общем следующая, только установленная винда, конкретно от винды установились все драйвера, обновления и тд, устанавливаю Discord, Telegram, Steam, Google Chrome, GeForce Experience, Bandizip, игры - GTA V и Dota 2, ничего не скачиваю и так далее, пользуюсь-пользуюсь, устанавливаю Visual Studio 2022 и Sea of Thieves, на следующее утро, захожу в ГТА 5 и понимаю, что все лагает, видимо упала производительность, при этом, когда ничего такого не открыто, сидя к примеру в браузере, бывает на секунду застывает ноутбук, когда что-то пытаешься сделать и слышно как, что-то запускается в ноутбуке (вентиляторы возможно, хотя они и так работают). По обновлениям винды, заметил что на тот момент, когда это +- произошло, что-то там обновилось для Microsoft Defender Antivirus. Заметив это, решил выключить его, путем переключения всех выключателей и заметил, что это немного помогло, вроде как, стало не так сильно лагать. Решил переустановить винду(делал до того, как узнал про защитник), бац, все нормально, все идеально, нет ничего такого, проходит опять месяц и опять начинаются лаги... Во время лагов всех эти лагов, кулера не так иногда работают(слышно что работают, как будто ничего не запущено что-ли(вроде как), например как после переустановки винды(слышно что работают как нужно, охлаждают и тд), когда все нормально. Самое интересное, что переустановка винды, это фиксит, буквально +- на месяц, и опять все по новой, от чего и как это зависит, не понятно....

Comment: Смотрели использование диска, проца, памяти? "Производительность системы".

Comment: Удали ГТА и Доту и не ставь больше ) Постать антивирус хороший и не ходи на подозрительные сайты.

Comment: наступать на одни и те же грабли? Скорее всего у вас одну программу или игру скачиваете каждый раз после переустановки, вот и вам такой результат.

Comment: Так то всё что угодно может быть вплоть до того, что какой-нибудь криптомайнер ставится и грузит систему )

Comment: Ну так ставь чистую винду ставь студию, доту, потом сохраняешь весь раздел с помощью clonezilla, а когда начнёт лагать - за 10 минут откатываешься обратно. Файло на D:\, история браузера - в синке. Все счастливы.